# Markers are not shown before Hot reload on the google map, flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I added the markers to googlemap.

In this code. At the first load, there is no markers

When I push `r` for hot reload , markers appear

I just guess,, I might have to do something here???

```
setState((){
  print("items ready and set state");
});
```

How can I solve this??

```
class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {

  Completer<gmap.GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  Set<gmap.Marker> _markers = {};


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _asyncMethod();
    print("init ready");
  }

  _asyncMethod() async {
    _markers = {};

    print ("asyncMethod start");
    
    List<dynamic> wayLabels = annotModel['wayLabel'];
    wayLabels.forEach((x){
      gmap.BitmapDescriptor icon;
      gmap.BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
            x['image'][CommonFunc.langKey]).then((onValue) {
            icon = onValue;
            gmap.Marker marker = gmap.Marker(
              markerId: gmap.MarkerId(x['title']),
              position: gmap.LatLng(x['latitude'],x['longitude']),
              icon: icon
            );
            _markers.add(marker);
        });
    });
    
    setState((){
      print("items ready and set state");
    });
  }
  Widget makeMyMap(){
    gmap.GoogleMap myMap = gmap.GoogleMap(
      mapType: gmap.MapType.normal,
      markers : _markers,
      initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
      onMapCreated: (gmap.GoogleMapController controller) {
        _controller.complete(controller);
      }
    );
    return Container(child:myMap);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return 
      Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child:Stack(children: <Widget>[
            makeMyMap(),
          ]),),
      ]);
  }
}
```

---

`gmap.BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage` might takes time so

```
    setState((){
      print("items ready and set state");
    });
```

in `_asyncMethod()`

was called before every markers are set.

That was the problem.

---

Solution.

change `_markers.add(marker);`

to

```
setState((){
  _markers = markers;
  print("items ready and set state");
});
```

it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using this package https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout.
Call _asyncMethod inside afterFirstLayout method

```
@override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    // Calling the same function "after layout" to resolve the issue.
    _asyncMethod();
  }
```

also, i think is healthier to assign the markers in _asyncMethod to a local variable an then in the setState change the markers

```
_asyncMethod() async {
    var localMarkers = {};

    .
    .
    .
    
    setState((){
        _markers = localMarkers;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much I am trying the later way.but found final setState() method in `async` is called before  every procedure finishes.

Comment: o yes, to test that you can use the mounted property https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html

Comment: Thank basically your second idea using local variable is the best way. There was another problem that setState*() is called before`gmap.BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage` was finished though. However it is soved. I added to my article.